# Symmetric blend modes

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, blend-mode

I draw a lot of images where semi-transparent regions of different colors mix. Now, the color of the intersection obviously depends on the order in which the regions are drawn (at least in the normal blend mode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[red,opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
        \fill[blue,opacity=0.5] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue,opacity=0.5] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
        \fill[red,opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Are there blend modes (or other ways to achieve this) for which the color of the intersection of the two rectangles does not depend on the order (at best, also also for more than two layers)? Of course, the color should still be recognizable as denoting the intersection, which rules out blend modes like `exclude`.

Comment: The blend modes are documented in the [manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transparency#sec-23.3). The result might depend on renderer/printer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `blend mode=screen`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend mode=screen]
\fill[red ,opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[blue,opacity=0.5] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm] % <-- I want the figures joined
  \fill[blue,opacity=0.5] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
  \fill[red ,opacity=0.5] (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why it isn't the default behaviour.